# Apache rewrite, home page

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the "home page" of the website to `www.example.com`.

The home page right now can be accessed via `www.example.com/dir/userdo?action=home`

My thoughts are `www.example.com` is really `www.example.com/index.html` since apache auto hide the `/index.html`, so I tried

`RewriteRule /index.html /dir/user.do?action=home [PT,L]`

which does not work.

Can someone give me an idea the right approach to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^/$ /dir/userdo?action=home [L]`

the default index.html can be changed with `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Comment: ty, the page now shows up, but all the css, images which are under `dir/cssimage` failed to load. I check the web console, which seems application is requesting `/cssimage` directory which does not exists under root folder. any idea what went wrong?

Comment: this rewrite rule does not affect the url which browser think all resources should be located at / (eg. /cssimage). Here is addition rules to fix that, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/$1 [L]` . These rules will redirect all request that file not exists to /dir/ .